# Best way to limit maximum executions of Azure durable functions activity per timespan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Being rather new to the Azure Durable Functions landscape, I am struggling to find the best way to handle downstream calls to an API that has rate limits implemented.

The way my flow is set up, is like below:

- **HistorySynchronizer_HttpStart** function: has `HttpTrigger` and `DurableClient` bindings in the signature and calls the next orchestration function:
- **HistorySynchronizer** function: has `OrchestrationTrigger` binding in the signature.  This function will make a call to the API (await) and get a collection back.  For every item in that collection, it will start a new Activity: `context.CallActivityAsync()` (combining them in a `List` and perform a `Task.WhenAll()`)
- **ProcessActivity** functions: has `ActivityTrigger` binding in the signature.  This function will have to make a call to the rate-limited API endpoint.  And it's these activities I want to throttle (across multiple orchestrations).

So, what I am looking for is an implementation to a throttling pattern:

- I need a shared state that is thread-safe (I was thinking about Durable Entity) that keeps track of the number of calls made to that API
- Before the ProcessActivity function makes the call to that API, it has to check with the Durable Entity if it can call the API, or if it has to wait a certain TimeSpan before performing that call.
- In case it has to wait, the Activity would have to 'sleep', and I was thinking about a Durable Timer, but it seems that should be used in an Orchestration function, instead of an Activity function.
- In case the call to the API is allowed, the Activity has to update the Rate counter in that shared state object.

I don't see a standard implementation to achieve this and I want to move as much of that Check/Sleep logic away from the main orchestration.

Would the best approach be to have a suborchestration implemented for every API call that has to be throttled, where the check has to happen, before the Activity is called?

Looking forward to any insights.

Comment: please see my response here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sH4t3cs9qkM

Answer (score 1):

Sam, I see several options. I've also created a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sH4t3cs9qkM) as a response to this. Let's step back and see how we would do this using regular functions (not durable).

The first approach would be to turn the function into a queue-triggered function, and use the queue mechanism to control scale out, by using `batchSize` and `newBatchThreshold`:

[image]

The other way would be to have an http-triggered function and use this in the host.js file:

[image]

With durable functions we can do this:

[image]

You specifically asked regarding controlling scale-out per timespan, and this is how I would do this:

1. convert your activity function to be queue-triggered
2. upon every execution of the queue-triggered function, this function insert a record into table storage indicating that there's an active run
3. prior to actually triggering the external http call, ping the table storage to see how many active connections there are.
4. if there are under X number of current connections, then process the message (i.e. make the external call), **if table storage shows that all the connections are taken, then put the message back on the queue!**

Comment: Thanks Alex for taking so much of your time in answering the above.  My aim was to rely as much as possible on Durable Functions, as they seem to have Durable sleeps (Timers), Durable Entities (so why do I need to bother with Table storage, if the framework provides something).  I was hoping to do this without relying on service bus queues.  The above option would be more of a fallback in case Durable Functions does not offer something out of the box

Comment: hey sam, i dont believe that OOB durable functions has anything like this. durable entities are an awesome option, i've got no experience with them, but i've had great experience hammering on table storage from many threads

Comment: from what i understand about durable entities, they are only available during the scope of the orchestration. another words, when your durable client is done, that data is no longer available to future execusion of your durable function app

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do it. Instead of trying to limit it on your side based on concurrent activity functions or active http requests, why don't you rely on the API itself? It knows when it's time to return 429.

I would add a queue, grab a task, call the API, if there is 429, put the task message back into the queue with an exponential delay policy.

Comment: I have a similar situation now.  Instead of a 429 response the API will give our system a 10 minute IP ban, which takes down the whole app

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario like Sam, but with one main difference which complicates the problem even more.

In may case there is a multiple orchestrator functions calling each other in a nested way.

Each one of them basically does the same:

- Get an API resource from activity function
- Go over the response items and call one or more sub-orchestrators functions. (Until the bottom of the tree)
- Return the response to the parent orchestrator.

The idea is to copy an entire Rest API to Azure data lake as part of an ETL process. (The extract layer)

For example: Customers => Orders => Invoices

Now, I can’t use the above solutions (working with a queue to control the rate) because I want each orchestrator to wait to the activity result and only then do the nested calls based on the activity result.

I’m thinking on another solution, one that will work with a synchronized orchestration tree.

1. Create a wrapping orchestration function around the activity
   function we want to throttle. (we can't wait from activity) This
   function will do the following:

   - add it's own instance id to some storage queue
   - [wait for an external event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=javascript#wait-for-events) - "HttpRequestAllowed"
   - continue as normal. (call the activity, do the next tasks)
2. Create a separate [client function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=csharp%2C2x-durable-functions#orchestration-client) that do the following:

   - read one instance id from the queue
   - raise an "HttpRequestAllowed" event to this instance id
   - wait some time (by rate limit) and handle the next instance id
   - continue until end of run

That way the current setup should continue to work in the same way, and when there are no external events waiting the orchestrators will be unloaded from the worker by Azure until new event coming.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [ThrottlingTroll](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll)'s egress rate limiting capabilities in your activity function.

Configure ThrottlingTroll-equipped HttpClient instance like this:

```
private static HttpClient ThrottledHttpClient = new HttpClient
(
    new ThrottlingTrollHandler
    (
        async (limitExceededResult, httpRequestProxy, httpResponseProxy, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var egressResponse = (IEgressHttpResponseProxy)httpResponseProxy;
            egressResponse.ShouldRetry = true;
        },

        counterStore: new AzureTableCounterStore(),

        // One request per each 5 seconds
        new ThrottlingTrollEgressConfig
        {
            Rules = new[]
            {
                new ThrottlingTrollRule
                {
                    LimitMethod = new FixedWindowRateLimitMethod
                    {
                        PermitLimit = 1,
                        IntervalInSeconds = 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
);
```

And then use it to make API calls. That HttpClient instance will limit itself, aka when the rate limit (in this example, 1 request per 5 seconds) is exceeded, it will automatically wait for the next chance to make a call (without making actual calls).

AzureTableCounterStore is used here for simplicity (doesn't require any external storages), but for production workloads I definitely recommend [RedisCounterStore](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/ThrottlingTroll.CounterStores.Redis#throttlingtrollcounterstoresredis) instead.

[Here is the full example of a .NET 6 InProc Function project](https://github.com/scale-tone/ThrottlingTroll/tree/main/samples/ThrottlingTrollSampleDotNet6InProcDurableFunction#throttlingtrollsampledotnet6inprocdurablefunction).